# Select or unselect check boxes - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have managed to create my function to select a single or multiple boxes. On the single ones I don't have any issue, I mean when you click a box it is checked or unchecked.

But it is not the same case with the select all. Any ideas how can I fix that? (I am using `material-ui` library for my boxes, but basically they are simple `HTML` input)

**Select all component and function:**

```
<Checkbox
    name="checkboxes"
    checked={this.state.allCheckboxes}
    onChange={this.handleAllCheckboxes}
    indeterminate
    />Select All
```

**Function:**

```
handleAllCheckboxes = (e) => {
    let responseObj = this.state.items;
    let prepareObj = {};
    if(e.target.checked){
        //to do add loop to check all check box
        responseObj.forEach(function(item){
            if(item.documentId !== null && item.documetNumber !== null ){
                prepareObj[item.documentId] = item.documentNumber;
                // this.refs.documentId
            }
        });
        let toSee = Object.keys(prepareObj).length > 0 ? true : false;
        this.setState({
            docList: prepareObj,
            visible: toSee
        })
        let checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('DocCheckbox')
        checkboxes.forEach(function(checkbox){
            checkbox.checked = checkbox.checked
            })
            console.log(checkboxes)
    } else {
        //to do add loop to uncheck all check box
        this.setState({
            prepareObj: {}
        })
    }

    console.log(prepareObj);

};
```

**Select single component and function:**

```
<Checkbox
      name='DocCheckbox'
      type='checkbox'
      color='default'
      value={JSON.stringify({ documentId: rowData.documentId, documentNumber: rowData.documentNumber })}
      onClick={this.handleCheckboxClick}/>
```

**Function:**

```
handleCheckboxClick = (e, id) => {

    if (id) {


    } else {
        let parsedVal = JSON.parse(e.target.value);
        // console.log(e.target.value)
        let newDocList = { ...this.state.docList };
        if (e.target.checked) {
            this.setState({
                singleCheckbox:true
            })
            newDocList[parsedVal.documentId] = parsedVal.documentNumber;
        } else {
            delete newDocList[parsedVal.documentId];
            this.setState({
                singleCheckbox:false
            })
        }
        let toSee = Object.keys(newDocList).length > 0 ? true : false;
        this.setState(
            {
                docList: newDocList,
                visible: toSee
            },
            () => {
                console.log(this.state.docList);
            }
        );

    }
};
```

**UPDATE**
*Answer of my code based to the reply of **@norbitrial***
( The answer is based on my properties , calls and data so feel free to modify it for your purpose )

**Step 1 -** *Create a constructor to maintain your data and global checked state*

```
 constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { 
            docList: {},
            checked: false,
            hasToCheckAll: false
       }
    }
```

**Step 2 -** *Create functions to handle single and multiple checkboxes*

*Handle single checkbox*

```
   handleCheckboxClick = (clickedItem) => {
        console.log(clickedItem)
        // let parsedVal = JSON.parse(e.target.value);
        let newDocList = { ...this.state.docList };
        if (!clickedItem.checked) {
            newDocList[clickedItem.documentId] = clickedItem.documentNumber;
            console.log(newDocList)
        } else {
            delete newDocList[clickedItem.documentId];
        }
        let toSee = Object.keys(newDocList).length > 0 ? true : false;
        console.log(toSee)
        this.setState(
            {
                docList: newDocList,
                visible: toSee
            }, ()=>{
                console.log(newDocList)
            });

        const updatedArray = this.state.items.map((item) => {
            item.checked = item.documentId === clickedItem.documentId ? !item.checked : item.checked;
            return item;
        });

        this.setState({

            items: updatedArray,
        });
    };
```

*Handle all checkboxes*

```
  handleAllCheckboxes = (e) => {
        const hasToCheckAll = !this.state.hasToCheckAll;
        const updatedArray = this.state.items.map((item) => {
            item.checked = hasToCheckAll;
            return item;
        });
        console.log(updatedArray)

        let responseObj = this.state.items;
        let prepareObj = {};
        if (e.target.checked) {
            //to do add loop to check all check box
            responseObj.forEach(function (item) {
                if (item.documentId !== null && item.documetNumber !== null) {
                    prepareObj[item.documentId] = item.documentNumber;

                }
            });
            let toSee = Object.keys(prepareObj).length > 0 ? true : false;
            console.log(toSee)
            this.setState({
                docList: prepareObj,
                // allCheckboxes: true,
                items: updatedArray,
                hasToCheckAll,
                visible: toSee
            })
            let checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('checkAll')
            checkboxes.forEach(function (checkbox) {
                checkbox.checked = e.target.checked

            })
            console.log(checkboxes)
        } else {
            console.log(updatedArray)
            this.setState({
                docList: {},
                hasToCheckAll:false
            })

        }
    };
```

**Step 3 -** *Insert the state of the checked boxes inside into the object . And loop over them ( again this is coming from the response from my Back End so for everyone this step will be different )*

```
  .then((response) => {
                // handle success

                let dataItem = response.data.bills;
                let prepareDataItem = [];
                dataItem.forEach(function (item) {
                    item.checked = false;
                    prepareDataItem.push(item);
                })
```

**Step 4 -** *Render the checkboxes (these checkboxes are based on `material-ui` library , but it can work for a simple inputs also)*

```
 <Checkbox
       name='DocCheckBox'
       type='checkbox'
       checked={rowData.checked}
       color='default'
       value={JSON.stringify({ documentId: rowData.documentId, documentNumber: rowData.documentNumber })}
       onChange={() => this.handleCheckboxClick(rowData)}/>


   <Checkbox
        name="checkboxes"
        checked={this.state.hasToCheckAll}
        onChange={this.handleAllCheckboxes}
        indeterminate
        />Select All
```

Comment: Is there some reason to use this approach with `docList`? Are you ok with a solution that  uses a different approach?

Comment: Thru `docList` i'm filling my object with the value of the checkboxes ... either a single or multiple . Later on `docList` is sended to the BE as an object and he returns me the documents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change a bit how you are handling these things in the application.

Technically you are manipulating the DOM directly, instead of leaving it to React with its states. In this case there is a definitely better way to handle checkbox states in the UI.

***The solution:***

**1. Changed default state:**

Let me state that I don't have the real data structure what you have so I have the following in the constructor just for the representation:

```
constructor(props:any) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        items: [
            { documentId: 1, documentNumber: 1234, checked: false },
            { documentId: 2, documentNumber: 1235, checked: false },
            { documentId: 3, documentNumber: 1236, checked: false },
        ],
        hasToCheckAll: false,
    }
}
```

As you can see the items have `checked` property in order to handle them in the state.

**2. Rendering the checkboxes differently**

In the render function I have changed couple of things:

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <Checkbox
                name="checkboxes"
                checked={this.state.hasToCheckAll}
                onChange={() => this.handleAllCheckboxes()}
                indeterminate
                />Select All

            {this.state.items.map((item:any) => {
                return <div key={item.documentNumber}>
                    <Checkbox
                        name="DocCheckbox"
                        color="default"
                        checked={item.checked}
                        value={JSON.stringify({ ...item.documentId, ...item.documentNumber })}
                        onChange={() => this.handleCheckboxClick(item)}/> {item.documentNumber}
                </div>
            })}
    </div>
    )
}
```

**3. Handling checkbox state is also changed:**

Take a look at the following handlers:

```
handleAllCheckboxes = () => {
    const hasToCheckAll = !this.state.hasToCheckAll;
    const updatedArray = this.state.items.map((item:any) => {
        item.checked = hasToCheckAll;
        return item;
    });

    this.setState({
        ...this.state,
        items: updatedArray,
        hasToCheckAll: hasToCheckAll,
    });
};

handleCheckboxClick = (clickedItem:any) => {
    const updatedArray = this.state.items.map((item:any) => {
        item.checked = item.documentId === clickedItem.documentId ? !item.checked : item.checked;
        return item;
    });

    this.setState({
        ...this.state,
        items: updatedArray,
    });
};
```

***The result:***

[image: result-gif]

Of course you can extend this example with your data manipulation if there is a further need. The solution has been built with `TypeScript` - I had a project opened with that - but you can remove types where it has been added.

The above example works like charm, I hope this helps!

Comment: Yes , it is something like this example https://codesandbox.io/s/vvxpny4xq3 , but unfortunately i cannot fill in my object `items` (by me `docList`) with the property `chekced: false` , because it is sended to the BE and it returns me an error .

Comment: Where it gives you the error and what is that? What do you mean by "it's sent to the BE"? Can you help me to understand?

Comment: No worries mate . Your example actually helped me a lot . By your answer i modified my code and now it's working . Thanks a lot !!!

Comment: Great, happy to help!

Comment: I have updated my question with the answer init based on your response . Im really glad that is working like a charm !